# How to design hierarchy (tree) table to display Drop-down menu?

Tags: python, django

I have I table name `Layer`
Which has 4 field : `layer1,layer2,layer3,layer4`

the model

```
class Layer(models.Model):
    layer1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    layer2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    layer3 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    layer4 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Because it's not standard format
it can something like `city/Building/Floor/department` or   `city/Floor/department`
This is depend on user,only rules is at most to 4 layer

for example:

```
layer 1 : city A 
layer 2 : Building A
layer 3 : 12 F 

layer 1 : city A 
layer 2 : Building A
layer 3 : 10 F
layer 4 : department A 

layer 1 : city B
layer 2 : 3 F

layer 1 : city B
layer 2 : 3 F
layer 3 : department A
```

and after the setting 
we need to present a Drop-down related menu on web page like this [enter link description here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Lx3tG2Ha10Y/Ue41LLoNT-I/AAAAAAAAA1c/YXxfIGmW-4E/s1600/Fill+Country,State+and+City+DropDownList+using+Ajax+CascadeDropDown+in+asp.net.gif)

My thought now is first query ,the user can choose layer1

```
layer1 = Layer(Q~(layer1=''),layer2='',layer3='',layer4='')
```

If he choose `city A` ,then

```
layer2 = Layer(layer1='city A',Q(layer2=''),layer3='',layer4='')
```

If he choose `Building A`,then

```
layer3 = layer2.filter(layer2='Building A',Q(layer3=''),layer4='')
```

And so on

But this seems not effectively.
I want to ask for directions how to do this would be great???

Comment: In my way I would change the model into a hierarchy (tree) table. The first query something like this: "model.filter(parent__isnull=True)" and in a template disable "building", "floor", "department" input. As soon as a user choose a city, send an AJAX to the server with value in previous input, query the parent, send back data in JSON for the select input and enable it.

Comment: Which Django version and database are you using?

Comment: I use django1.7 and postgresql

Comment: @Yaaaaaaaaaaay,could you explain how to design hierarchy (tree) table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An verbose explanation is [HERE](http://leopard.in.ua/2013/07/11/storing-trees-in-rdbms/) for the tree model.

An **imanigary model** I will be working with:

```
class NameOfTabel(models.Model):
    """docstrings"""
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)  # For 1.7 v. In 1.9 it's slightly different
    layer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Before we start, this model is supposed to be filled in the admin area or via prepopulated scripts because it would be "hard" to set validations for each layer if necessary.

The table has 3 columns:

```
id | parent_id | layer
```

The first layer has to have the `parent_id` field empty.

```
id | parent_id | layer
1  |           | city A
```

In the second layer, you have to assign "Building A" to the parent which is "City A" and it has #1 ID.

```
id | parent_id | layer
2  | 1         | building A
```

In the third and fourth layer is the setup same.

```
id | parent_id | layer
3  | 2         | 12 F
4  | 3         | department A
```

(If some layers may be empty then alter the CharField to `null=True`.)

If you look above you may get it why it's called a tree. If you picture that it would look like this: (I added more rows)

```
city A
    building A
        12 F
            department A
    building B
        1 F
            department B
city B
    building A
        2 F
            department A
```

For displaying in a "terminal" there must be (left) joins in a query and I hope that you can do it (with so many reputations points you have).

```
layer1 | layer2     | layer3 | layer4
city A | building A | 12 F   | department A
city A | building B | 1 F    | department B
city B | building A | 2 F    | department A
```

Now how to query the table for the purpose in the link you've provided:

1. layer = `NamOfTable.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull=True)`
2. layer = `NameOfTable.objects.filter(parent_id=id_from_ajax_call)`
3. layer = same as the #2
4. layer = same as the #2

If you look at it closely you will see some repeated codes, so I suggest to load the table into 1 variable and querying for the #2, #3, #4 placed into a variable e.g. "child".

Finally, a setup in a short way:

- first of all display on a client side in a first select box only layer 1, others will be disabled
- after choosen the layer 1, send a AJAX for displaying the child and in the sended data will be the parent ID
- in the views you will get from the sended data the parent id and query for results, send it back, display it in the select box for the layer 2 and allow it (cancel the disabled status)
- for the #3 and #4 layer same procedure as previous point.